# Another Undefined Offset Error

Tags: php

I am returning the JSON in the correct formatting but I am getting a

> Notice: Undefined offset 2

when I visit the page. I spent all last night trying to fix this and I can get the error to go away but then I only get one row of the data instead of all the data. I've tried to change the key names to numbers and still can't get it to work.

```
#part of a factory pattern thats called by getIt()
public function selectAll($where='')
{
$stmt = $this->dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$where}");
$stmt->execute();
$this->results = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $this;
}

#cheap-api.php
$output = $work->getIt('person')->results();

for($i=0; $i<=count($output); $i++) {
$response['person'][$i] = [];
$response['person'][$i]['fname'] = $output[$i]['fname'];
$response['person'][$i]['lname'] = $output[$i]['lname'];
}

 print_r(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

**This is the output:**

```
{
 "person": [
        {
            "fname": "mitthe",
            "lname": "mormon"
        },
        {
            "fname": "jambi",
            "lname": "myeyes"
        },
        {
            "fname": null,
            "lname": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't the loop-continuation condition use the < operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1:

after this line:

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($output); $i++) {
```

just insert this line:

```
if(!array_key_exists($i, $output)) continue;
```

## Solution 2:

just replace `<=` with `<` like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($output); $i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that notice because the offset 2 really doesn't exist. The only reason you're looking for offset 2 is because of the loop condition `<=count($output)`. The count is 2, so `$i` will be 0, 1, and then 2. You can avoid this a few different ways. Two are shown in the other answer. Another way is to use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach ($output as $person) {
    $response['person'][] = ['fname' => $output['fname'], 'lname' => $output['lname']];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the example Don't Panic, most definitely thanks for the useful information and for another answer that works.